# Access roles in oauth.getToken response vert.x keycloak

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, vert.x, keycloak

I am using the code below to 1) Login the user on keycloak, 2) Verify if the user has the specific role to access some resource.

```
JsonObject keycloakJson = new JsonObject()
        .put("realm", "OQM") // (1)
        .put("realm-public-key", "MIIBIwercerewrcewrc7BAij3P+Nz76opTVlhWijnIGefnBygViDrUdxS/nZSDTkXrFnKy2lpNZyecWrNVD6Zs6w65pBa60zDWODkuIqE6LbbfwHBs5RyvuzAFRtRFbieZub8x4suzN5pJOUPWdtgWqQasdawercwerewvrewrvewrcwxewrvbewvrxw9k+TPKGdf3e9QXL9FGG/9084+6Z8RSZ4JL4v5YqVtpDyohf9MPJwn/i46KcAYzgleJFFCqwuPry8CEzafqXVlzIEkSqwIDAQAB") // (2)
        .put("auth-server-url", "http://152.18.17.63:8080/auth")
        .put("ssl-required", "external")
        .put("resource", "oqm") // (3)
        .put("credentials", new JsonObject().put("secret", "2343253252-c8f1-42b2-866c-87a2a7ff95f6")); // (4)

OAuth2Auth oauth2 = KeycloakAuth.create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.PASSWORD, keycloakJson);

JsonObject tokenConfig = new JsonObject().put("username", "dummyUser").put("password", "password").put("scope", "modify-account view-account");

oauth2.getToken(tokenConfig, res -> {
    if (res.failed()) {
        rc.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code()).end();
    } else {
        AccessToken token = (AccessToken)res.result();
        token.isAuthorised("ReleaseOrders", handler -> {
            if(handler.result()) {
                HttpServerResponse response = VerticleUtils.buildOKHeaders(rc);
                response.end(Json.encodePrettily(token.principal()));
            }
            else {
                VerticleUtils.notAuthorized(rc);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However, I need to get a list of roles user is authorized for. I can see the roles in a property of the 
**AccessToken** object returned, but since its access is private I cant access them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using `principal()`? It should hold JSONObject and within it, you should find roles.

Comment: the principal just returns the token property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can only get the full token from the `principal()` method call. For 3.5.1 we're are working on exposing the token from the `AcessToken` object.

Comment: Who is we and what is 3.5.1 version from?

Comment: I’m the main developer of the oauth2 code and I was speaking in the name of the team. 3.5.1 is the current in development version.